# Xcode ViewController elements is not interactive after animation

Tags: swift3, interface-builder, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint, cgaffinetransform

I have a project that need to have a **top sheet**, that when user scrolling *down* it will *reveal*. so I created 2 separate `ViewController` in `storyboard` like this:

[image]

in the main `ViewController` I add the sheet view controller as a subview like this:

```
let topSheet = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "top_sheet_vc") as! TopSheetVC
self.addChildViewController(topSheet)
self.view.addSubview(topSheet.view)
topSheet.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
topSheet.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topSheet.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: Constant.TOP_SHEET_HEIGHT)
let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topSheet.view, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topSheet.view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topSheet.view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([height, leading, trailing, bottom])
```

Then I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that attached to the main view of main view controller, and in the handler method I can move the view so the top sheet can be revealed, like this:

```
func panGestureHappened(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let y = self.view.frame.minY
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    let min = fmin(y + translation.y, Constant.TOP_SHEET_HEIGHT)
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: min)

    // or I can change the frame, same result as CGAffineTransform
    // self.view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: min, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
}
```

so far so good, the top sheet reveals and become visible and the main view is shifting down as I expected.

The **Problem** is that the top sheet is not interactive and **clickable** and I can't figure out what is wrong with this.

so any help or tip would be appreciated.

tnx in advance.

**NOTE**: If I animate the `TopSheet` not the base view, so the top sheet `overlap` the base view, and not shifting down the base view the problem will be gone and `TopSheet` is *clickable*. But I can't figure out **why**.

**UPDATE**: I eliminate all the custom constraints and added a `ContainerView` in the main controller inside storyboard, and the container has negative value for top to bring it outside, and when the main view get animated and top is revealed But it is still not clickable, BUT if I overlay the container it became clickable again, so there is something related to view **height**, any idea?

Comment: Maybe something like `makeKeyAndOrderFront` is what you want...

Comment: @l'L'l can you be more specific? I use `makeKeyAndOrderFront` in AppDelegate, first time the app starts to show the first `ViewController`, how can it help me with this problem?

Comment: Well it seems like your top sheet might not have focus, so you might need a function that brings it to the top so that you can interact with it. `makeKeyAndOrderFront` does that with layers and NSWindow's on macOS, so maybe you need something similar for your iOS storyboards.

Comment: For the part you don't want to have focus you'd use `orderOut`... If this isn't what the problem is then just disregard my comments.

Comment: There is a method for bringing a view to front `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: (topSheetVC?.view)!)`. But it won't help either.

Comment: @l'L'l Please Note that if I animate the `TopSheet` not the base view, so the top sheet overlap the base view, and not shifting down the base view the problem will be gone and `TopSheet` is clickable. But I can't figure out why.

Comment: This might be possibly helpful: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout

Comment: tnx for the link, based on the link I think this is the problem: `auto layout and animation`, I'm trying to solve it but any help or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: @l'L'l, ok I eliminate all the custom constraint, actually I add I `ContainerView` in the main controller inside `storyboard`, and the container has negative value for top to bring it outside, But it is still not clickable, BUT if I overlay the container it became clickable again, so there is something related to height, any idea?